# AWS Cognito App Client View Hosted UI redirects without displaying original UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I configured a Cognito User Pool with an App Client enabled with Hosted UI. After first successful signup operation View Hosted UI starts to redirect right away even before displaying its original UI. I signed out from the recently signed in user from console itself. Additionally, I cleared out all the Local Storage, Session Storage and Cookies related to localhost (I am in development phase so using localhost as redirect URLs). On the other hand, if I open hosted ui in private mode then it stars to display. Any idea about how can I fix this? Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should navigate to the [cognito's logout endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) from your browser. This will invalidate the cognito hosted UI session present (cookies).

From your application, when a user signs out, you should do the same. The SDK's like Amplify, signout function would do this for you if you are using it.

Comment: Thanks @callo but how is that different from signing out from the cognito console? I remember that I also did signed out by Amplify's javascript sdk.

Comment: The logout endpoint invalidates the HostedUI cookies that keep your session alive currently. You can see this by reviewing the headers in the browser. 

I would assume the sign out function in the console invalidates the Oauth tokens for the user only.

In theory I believe that should invalidate there HostedUI session too but does not seem to be a feature Cognito supports.

Comment: Not sure but I tested by clearing out all cookies from firefox and it worked. Problem resolved. Thanks